# How to create directories using foreach in chef (with attributes)

Tags: chef-infra

How do I create multiple directories if my array has attributes in it?

From the chef directory resource documentation I have tested with sample code below and this works. However, I am having trouble if the array contains attributes, and I am not quite sure how to see what it's doing.

```
%w( /foo /foo/bar /foo/bar/baz ).each do |path|
```

I have printed all of my variables and observed node.default[:user_home] to be /home/chefuser

```
# this creates /home/chefuser/.local
directory 'for storing local binaries' do
  path "#{node.default[:user_home]}/.local"
  owner 'chefuser'
  group 'chefuser'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end

# this does not create /home/chefuser/.local or /home/chefuser/.local/bin (however it doesn't fail)                                                                                                                                                                                                      
["#{node.default[:user_home]}/.local", "#{node.default[:user_home]}/.local/bin"].each do |path|                                                                                                                                                directory 'for storing local binaries' do                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    owner 'chefuser'
    group 'chefuser'
    mode '0755'
    action :create
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the name property of the resource is only one (`for storing local binaries`), and it does not iterate over the attributes passed as array.

For this `foreach` loop to work, you need to use the loop variable `path` in the resource.

Example of using it as "resource name":

```rb
[
  "#{node.default['user_home']}/.local",
  "#{node.default['user_home']}/.local/bin"
].each do |path|
  directory path do                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    owner 'chefuser'
    group 'chefuser'
    mode '0755'
    action :create
  end
end
```

Comment: I incorrectly assumed that the path property was getting set implicitly by using |path| as the variable name in the foreach. Thanks for the clarification!